# Correct way of changing View's Height and Width Android

Tags: android, android-layout

very new to android here! I am basically confused on how to change a View's Height and Width. Currently I have such (snippets):

*XML (Uses Relative layouts)*

```
<View
    android:id="@+id/homeBackgroundTop"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent" />
```

*Java*

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    int screenWidth = size.x;
    int screenHeight = size.y;

    final float pixelToDp = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int screenHeightDp =  (int) (screenHeight * pixelToDp + 0.5f);
    int screenWidthDp =  (int) (screenWidth * pixelToDp + 0.5f);

    View view = findViewById(R.id.homeBackgroundTop);
    view.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(screenWidthDp, screenHeightDp));

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

The problem is it is raising the follow FATAL ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.View.setLayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams)' on a null object reference
```

Now my question is, how can I correctly change a View's Height and Width programmatically? I have looked on many other SO answers, but none of them seem to work for me.

**P.S.** What exactly is `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` referring to? If I am trying to change a View, why would I be calling a Layout? Why does it sometimes also contain `LinearLayout`? Lastly, what exactly is LayoutParams? If you have links to any of these questions, it would be greatly appreciated :) Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` has not been called before you make your call to `findViewById()`.  Therefore no view can be found because your views have not been attached to your activity yet.

Put `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` at the beginning of onCreate or at least before you call `findViewById()`.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

To answer your **P.S.**  the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` allows you to set the basic layout parameters like height and width for the view object.  Your particular view (Button or TextView, etc...) likely inherits from either a LinearLayout or a RelativeLayout view.  The LayoutParams are apparently specific to the different Layout type (Relative vs Linear).  I am looking around for a more concrete answer that question for myself at the moment.  Let me know if you find anything on it.

Comment: Thank you, just got back on to do what you had mentioned, and it is working! :) Thank You!! **Oh yea**, so what exactly is the `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams` part? Why do I add the `RelativeLayout` part to such? Aren't I adding the params on to the `View`? Why isn't it `View.Params`? Please elaborate if you know!

Comment: Edited my answer to add my two cents on your question

Comment: Ok thank you. I was just wondering because I am setting a Height and Width specifically to the `View`, which is inside of a `RelativeLayout`. So I was not exactly sure why I would be setting the params to the parent. If I find anything out more on this I will let you know as well! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
    params.height = screenHeightDp;
    params.width = screenWidthDp;
    view.setLayoutParams(params);
```

So your `onCreate` method will be like this .

```
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        int screenWidth = size.x;
        int screenHeight = size.y;

        final float pixelToDp = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int screenHeightDp =  (int) (screenHeight * pixelToDp + 0.5f);
        int screenWidthDp =  (int) (screenWidth * pixelToDp + 0.5f);

        View view = findViewById(R.id.homeBackgroundTop);
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = view.getLayoutParams();
        params.height = screenHeightDp;
        params.width = screenWidthDp;
        view.setLayoutParams(params);

    }
```

One thing to be noted here always call setContentView() , just after calling `super.Oncreate` .

I have tested this . Please let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to cast to RelativeLayout which the error states it is wrong. You need another kind of casting.

Btw, setContentview should be right below super reference.
This means that you're trying to use View element from your XML, without calling the XML firstly.